# How to Update on Duplicate Key if the columns are not unique?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sql-update, sql-insert

How do I insert only when the 2 row values are not the same exactly? Here is my scenario so my question makes sense:

```
ID      employee_id     client_id
1           1              10
2           2              11
3           1              11
4           2              10
```

I want to insert something like this to the column in PDO:

```
insert into yourTableName (employee_id, client_id)
    values (:employee_id, :client_id)
    on duplicate key update 
        employee_id=:$employee_id2, client_id=:client_id2
```

But the [insert on duplicate](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) above only seems to work if one of them columns were unique. In my case, the values in employee_id and client_id are not unique and the values can repeat multiple times. However there can only be 1 combination of it.

How can I only insert the row only if the exact combination of column values doesnt exit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...` requires a unique key. The unique key can be on multiple columns. Simply create a multi-column unique key on both columns (employee_id, client_id).

There is a caveat to using `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...`. With default settings, if `ID` is an auto-increment column, the counter will increment each time you call `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...` even if it just updates because the next id is generated first. If that is a problem, you should use `SELECT FOR UPDATE` within a transaction to see if the record exists, then behave accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

`UNIQUE` constraint doesn't have to be limited to a single column.
You can alter your table like this:

```
ALTER TABLE `yourTableName` ADD UNIQUE `unique_index`(`employee_id`, `client_id`);
```

Answer (score 1):

> How can I only insert the row only if the exact combination of column values doesnt exit?

To do that you have to create a unique key with both column "employee_id" and "client_id".